# Who can prove that a triangular number cannot be a cube, fourth power or fifth power?

Tags: number-theory, perfect-powers

Triangular numbers (See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number )

are numbers of the form $$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

In ProofWiki I found three claims about triangular numbers. The three claims are that a triangular number cannot be a cube, not a fourth power and not a fifth power. Unfortunately, neither was a proof given nor did I manage to do it myself. Therefore my qeustions :

> Does someone know a proof that a triangular number cannot be a cube, a fourth power or a fifth power ?

Comment: [This page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicTriangularNumber.html) shows you why it can't be a cube.

Comment: Is this meant to be easy?  For cubes it looks like it follows from Catalan's Conjecture....so it is true, but...

Comment: Well, I still call it Catalan's conjecture because I am old.  The proof, by Mihăilescu, is well accepted.

Comment: How can I prove that a triangular number cannot be a cube using Catalan's conjecture ?

Comment: Oh:   $n(n+1)=2k^3 \implies 4n(n+1)=(2k)^3\implies (2n+1)^2-1=(2k)^3$.  But by Catalan you know that $9,8$ are the only consecutive perfect powers.

Comment: Wow, really impressive! Perhaps, you find similar proof for fourth and fifth powers.

Comment: For fourth powers...we know what the square triangular numbers are (from Pell's equation, if memory serves) so maybe we can see that none of the solutions are themselves squares.  I'll take a look a bit later.

Comment: Ok, that works.  Pell gives us the recursion $s_{n+1}=4\times s_n\times (8s_n+1)$ for the square triangular numbers.  Noting that $s_2=36$ we use the recursion to prove that $9\,|\,s_n$ but $81$ does not for all $n≥2$.

Comment: I got no immediate ideas on fifth powers, so I'll quit while I'm ahead!

Comment: @lulu Thank you for your informations so far!

Comment: Actually, I think the extended Catalan conjecture settles fifth powers as well:  $n(n+1)=2k^5\implies 16n^2+16n=(2k)^5\implies (4n+2)^2-4=(2k)^5$.  But I believe we know (via extended Catalan) that the only perfect powers that differ by $4$ are $(0,4),(4,8),(32,36),(121,125)$.  Note:  I would check to make sure I have that right....I'm not exactly sure what's been proven and what hasn't.

Comment: This reminds me of the classical Erdos and Selfridge paper (http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1975-46.pdf)

Comment: The case of a fourth power seems easy because it would only be necessary to show that with $B_1=1$ , $B_2=6$ , $B_{n}=6B_{n-1}-B_{n-2}$ , the sequence $B_n$ contains no perfect square except $B_1$. But I could not prove it only using modular arithmetic and quadratic residues.

Comment: Since you are interested in this kind of questions, here is a related problem that I am thinking now: problems about the radical of an integer, see this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer) and relations with [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber's_formula). I don't know if there is literature about speculative relations, see for instance that it is obvious $\operatorname{rad} \left( \sum_{k=1}^n k \right)= \frac{\operatorname{rad}(n)\operatorname{rad}(n+1)}{2}$, a sequence of integers. I am saying this if it is interesting for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem was finished off (for arbitrary powers) in a paper of Gyory in 1997 (Acta Arithmetica) :
http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa80/aa8038.pdf
There are no unexpected solutions. The proof appeals to Darmon and Merel's result on the equation $x^n+y^n=2z^n$ (though, with some care, it should be possible nowadays to prove it using only linear forms in logarithms).

Comment: Seems that an easy proof is out of reach, but if I understand it right we have the result that a triangle number cannot be a non-trivial perfect power with exponent greater than $2$, right ? By the wy, did you finish the verification of the mordell-curve-files ?

Comment: Still bug-checking. I'll upload them as txt files.

Answer (score 4):

First, notice $n$ and $n+1$ are coprime. And if the product of coprime numbers is a n-th power then both are also n-th powers. Now divide the problem into the cases where $n$ is odd and even.
$$n=2t$$
$$t(2t+1)=a^b$$
Then $t$ and $2t+1$ are b-th powers. Let $t=y^b$, $2t+1=x^b$. Then 
$$x^b-2y^b=1$$
Applying the same substitutions to the case where $n$ is odd you find $$x^b-2y^b=-1$$
In [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/257131) Keith Conrad proves the only solution is $x=1$, $y=0$, which mean $n=0$.