# If $8x^p+1$ is a square for an odd prime $p$, then $p\mid x-1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> For an odd prime $p$ and a positive integer $x$, prove that if $8x^p+1$ is a perfect square, then $p$ divides $x-1$.

I've tried modulo $p$ and factorizing with $8x^p=k^2-1$. It gives some sort of equation like $a^p-2b^p=1$ which does not help. I also tried $x=pk+1+r$ but didn't go well. The most curious part of this problem is that there seems to be no relationship between $x-1$ and $p$ (perhaps $x$ or $p$ maybe).

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Please include more context via an [edit]. More details are in the banner and the linked thread there.

Comment: This is false btw. Let $p=3,x=83232$ then $\sqrt{8x^3+1} = 67917312$ and $p|x$ thus $p\nmid x-1$

Comment: @above But the square root of $8x^3+1$ should always be a odd number. Something's wrong with your counterexample.

Comment: Do you have any examples of perfect squares of the form $8x^p+1$ with $p$ an odd prime, never mind whether $p | x-1$?  Notice that if $8n+1$ is a perfect square $s^2$ then $n$ is a triangle number since $n = [(s/2-1/2)(s/2+1/2)/2]$.  But answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2185585/who-can-prove-that-a-triangular-number-cannot-be-a-cube-fourth-power-or-fifth-p) strongly suggest a triangle number cannot be a perfect power with exponent greater than two.

Comment: Actually, I couldn't find any $x$s without 1 that makes $8x^p+1$ a perfect square. The approach with the triangle number seems very interesting, which remains to show the existence of $x$ which satisfies $x^p=n(n+1)/2$.

Comment: And I see some results from H. Darmon and L. Merel who proved that there are no such $x$ when $p\le3$, which completes the problem. But the proof of it uses a lot of non-elementary NT methods like the elliptic curve. I think I can prove the given statement only with elementary number theory methods.

Comment: @Anvit $x=2\times204^2$ in your example, so that $8x^3$ is a square, and $8x^3+1$ is only close to it.

Comment: @URL Makes sense, I'm pretty sure I was using Python so maybe floating point error caused this mistake.